# Azure Devops Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to build a YAML release pipeline in Azure devops.
I already have YAML build pipeline.
I can see that when i do a YAML build Azure devops is making azure-pipelines.yml which is checked into a master branch of code repo. 
Now if I want a separate YAML release (CD) pipeline how can I do it, because when click release there is YAML creation option.

[image: Release option].
[image: Release no YAML option]

Or do i have to add release to the existing azure-pipelines.yml which already has the build. In this case my build and release is all in one file. how can i then control the release and in some case reject the releases? What is the recommended approach? A bit lost in this YAML CI/CD.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable multi-staged pipelines from the preview features. With them, you'll create just one yaml pipeline for both build and release. Do note that multi-stage pipelines still lack some of the features available in editor-based release pipelines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops

Comment: Having started with a CI Pipeline (build) it really is not that obvious that to introduce a Release process in YAML you change to a multi stage YAML file that does build and deployment rather than a separate Release.YAML

Answer (score 0):

For others, who are checking this now, I tried to do this Azure way, but ended up not finding it feasible both cost wise and flexibility wise.

Ended up using FluxCD with Jenkins.